# Type error: argument of type 'method' is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am creating a source code based on school project and I am getting this error. I have checked it thoroughly but couldn't find anything.

```
loop1 = True
loop2 = False
 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.parsers import read_csv
 
filename = pd.read_csv("D:\\project ip MHN12B\\users.csv")
filename2 = pd.read_csv("D:\\project ip MHN12B\\avail.csv")
filename3 = pd.read_csv("D:\\project ip MHN12B\\orders.csv")
 
print("Welcome To The Online Dessert Shop")
 
while loop1:  
 
    print("1.login")
    print("2.register")
    print("3.exit")
 
    choice = int(input("Enter your choice:"))  
 
    if choice == 1: 
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col='usr')  
 
        uname = input("Enter your username:")
        passw = input("Enter your password:")  
 
        if True:  
            if True:  
                if uname in df.index:  
                    loginu = True
                else:  
                    loginu = False
 
            if loginu == False:  
                print("incorrect username,try again later")
                login = False
            else:
                if passw in df.loc[uname, 'passw']:  
                    login = True
                else: 
                    login = False
                    print("incorrect password,try again later")
                if login == False:
                    print("login failed")
                else: 
                    print("logged in")
                    loop1 = False
                    loop2 = True
    elif choice == 2:  
        uname = input("enter your username:")
        passw = input("enter your password:")
        email = input("enter your email:")
 
        df = read_csv(filename)  
        to_append = [uname.passw, email]
        df_Length = len(df)
        df.loc[df_length] = to_append
        df = df.set_index('usr')
        df.to_csv(filename)  

    elif choice == 3:  
        print("ok bye")  
        loop1 = False
    else:
        print("invalid choice")
 
while loop2:  
    print("1.view available desserts")
    print("2.place orders")
    print("3.bar graph of most purchased products")
    print("4.exit")
 
    choice2 = int(input("enter your choice:"))
 
    if choice2 == 1:
        df2 = pd.read_csv(filename2, index_col='itemno')  
        print(df2.iloc[:, :3])
    elif choice2 == 2:
        df3 = pd.read_csv(filename3)
        df2 = pd.read_csv(filename2, index_col='itemno')  
        itemno = input("enter item no of the product:")
        qty = int(input("enter quantity of the product:"))
        stock = df2.stock[itemno]
        bal = stock - qty
 
        
        if stock > bal:
            df2.orders[itemno] = df2.orders[itemno] + 1
            df2.stock[itemno] = bal
            to_append3 = [name, itemno, qty]
            df_length3 = len(df3)
            df33.loc[df_length3] = to_append3
            df3 = df3.set_index('usr')
 
            
            df3.to_csv(filename3)  
            df2.to_csv(filename2)  
            print("purchase successful amount of", df2.price[itemno], 'has been charged')


        else:
            print('insufficient stock')
 
    elif choice2 == 3:
       df3 = pd.read_csv(filename3)  
        df2 = pd.read_csv(filename2, index_col='itemno')
 
        plt.xlabel('desserts')
        plt.ylabel('no of desserts sold')

        plt.title('desserts sold')
        plt.bar(df2.product, df2.orders, width=0.5)
        plt.show()
 
    elif choice2 == 4:  
        print('bye bye')  
        loop2 = False
    else:
        print("invalid choice")
```

The above is the code and the below is the error shown .

```
Welcome To The Online Dessert Shop

1.login

2.register

3.exit

Enter your choice:1

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "F:\source code new.py", line 23, in <module>

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col='usr')

  File "C:\Users\mona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper

    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\mona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 586, in read_csv

    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Users\mona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 482, in _read

    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\mona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 811, in __init__

    self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)

  File "C:\Users\mona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1040, in _make_engine

    return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]

  File "C:\Users\mona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 51, in __init__

    self._open_handles(src, kwds)

  File "C:\Users\mona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\base_parser.py", line 222, in _open_handles

    self.handles = get_handle(

  File "C:\Users\mona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 585, in get_handle

    if _is_binary_mode(path_or_buf, mode) and "b" not in mode:

  File "C:\Users\mona\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 962, in _is_binary_mode

    return isinstance(handle, binary_classes) or "b" in getattr(handle, "mode", mode)

TypeError: argument of type 'method' is not iterable
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71395417/edit) your post and add triple backticks (```) to separate the code from the text? And remove unnecessary empty lines? And maybe also shorten your code to something that still reproduces your issue?

Comment: Maybe you could replace `filename = pd.read_csv("D:\project ip MHN12B\users.csv")` by `filename = r"D:\project ip MHN12B\users.csv"` to make `filename` a name of a file? Writing `r"...."` helps to indicate that backslash (`\\`) isn't interpreted as a special character.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of If-Statements that are confusing and not necessary. But I think the root of your problem is that you try to read a DataFrame with pandas.read_csv.

pandas.read_csv can be used to read a comma-separated values (csv) file into a DataFrame. You provide a DataFrame as argument for the filepath, which should be a string path.

```
filename = pd.read_csv("D:\project ip MHN12B\users.csv") # filename becomes a DataFrame
...

if choice == 1:
  df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col='usr') # filename should be a string path
```

So try changing to a string path.